# Parse Json to use in a dojo widget?

Tags: json, parsing, dojo, widget, digit

I am newbie to dojo and json. I am trying to Query the server to get data as json and parse the result and use html template in a widget to display.

To test it I tried this.

```
      require(["dojo/request", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct","dojo/_base/array", "my/widgets/", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(request, dom,domConst, arrayUtil, support){
// Load up our authors
request("js/my/data/sample.json", {
    handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(LinksMap){
        // Get a reference to our container



    arrayUtil.forEach(LinksMap, function(List){
        // Create our widget and place it

       console.debug(LinksMap);
        //var widget = new support(author).placeAt(authorContainer);
```

Not sure if I am doing it right. Is there anything I am misssing. I am following the example as provided [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/recipes/custom_widget/) and building on it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  What happens when the posted code runs?

Comment: I do not get any errors

Comment: if you print `console.log(LinksMap);` as the first line the deferred handler function, what prints?

Comment: Object { Result=[3], Request={...}}

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo it is too large to post it here. But I do see the complete json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think from the comments on your post you want to modified the deferred handling function to be

```
request("js/my/data/sample.json", {
    handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(jsonResults){
    console.log(jsonResults.Result)
});
```

The json you posted is an object with a property `Result`.  The `Result` property contains an array of objects.  Those objects then contain a property `LinksMap` which holds another object.

Comment: Thanks, how do I access the linksMap object

Comment: `LinksMap` is a property on each object in the `Result` array.  So to get the first `LinksMap` would be `jsonResults.Result[0].LinksMap`, the second would be `jsonResults.Result[1].LinksMap` and so on.